# How come there are skinny Mikvah attendants?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Halacha is quite clear:

> צָרִיךְ לְהַעֲמִיד עַל גַּבָּהּ יְהוּדִית גְּדוֹלָה יוֹתֵר מִי''ב שָׁנָה וְיוֹם אֶחָד בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁהִיא טוֹבֶלֶת, שֶׁתִּרְאֶה שֶׁלֹּא יִשָּׁאֵר מִשְּׂעַר רֹאשָׁהּ צָף עַל פְּנֵי הַמַּיִם
>
> A large Jewish woman, more than 12 years of age, must stand on her back while she immerses, to see to it that none of her hair floats above the water

I suppose that to make sure she goes deep enough under water, we must have a heavy woman weigh her down.

My wife has occasionally pointed out some of the "Mikvah Lady" volunteers, and none of them seem overly obese. And she has *never* mentioned anything about them climbing on her back!

What is the justification for such flagrant flaunting of Halacha?!?!?!?!?!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Someone was upset at me and decided to downvote my question and answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a prevalent attitude amongst the Poskim that *niskatnu hadoros*, the later generations became smaller.

Therefore, what used to require heavy weights can be accomplished with much less.

Answer (score 7):

No, no, no, you read it all wrong!

Obviously it doesn't mean that a heavy woman stands on her back, as this would constitute a *chatzitzah* (see S.A. [Y.D. 198:28](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5547)), possibly even if her feet were wettened with mikvah water (see Taz Y.D. 198:27).

Rather, it means they should have an *important* woman stand above her, from which position she can look down at her condescendingly. That way, the immersing woman will feel ashamed and want to sink further into the water, ensuring that no hair remains floating above.

This is also why the woman must be over the age of 12, which your silly interpretation doesn't account for - it's because no one feels looked down upon by little kids.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the halacha mentions a 12-year-old girl is because the size of a typical 12-year-old girl is the *shiur* for what is considered a "large woman". The reason the language says that the woman should be large is to emphasize that she must be big enough to push the woman dipping completely under water. But one doesn't have to be *so* huge to do this. Really a typical 12-year-old would be sufficient. That's why the *mikvah* attends don't have to be obese. As long as they're larger than a typical prepubescent, they're large enough.